# React Native Maps. Google Map turns back to initial location after on region change complete

Tags: react-native, google-maps-markers

I want registered users listed with markers on the map where he/she can see nearby app users. The map show initial markers but I cannot see dynamically assigned  markers besides the map stuck into its initial place. For example I drag the map to other locations when I finish dragging map, it turns back.

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Switch, Alert, AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import Fetchdata from './Fetchdata.js';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});

export default class Stage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style ={styles.container}>
        <Fetchdata />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

FetchData.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Switch, Alert, AppRegistry} from 'react-native'
import MapView, {Marker} from 'react-native-maps';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
  },
});
export default class Fetchdata extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
  }
  state = {
      latitude: 3.148561,
      longitude: 101.652778,
      markers: [{
    title: 'hello',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 3.148561,
      longitude: 101.652778
    },
      },
      {
    title: 'hello',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 3.149771,
      longitude: 101.655449
    },
      }]
   };
   componentDidMount = () => {
     navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
    this.setState({
      latitude: position.coords.latitude,
      longitude: position.coords.longitude,
      error: null,
    });

      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );
   }
   onRegionChange (region) {
     fetch('https://isg.info.tr/query_maps.php' + '?latitude=' + this.state.latitude + '&longitude=' + this.state.longitude , {
    method: 'GET'
     })
     .then((response) => response.json())
     .then((responseJson) => {
       const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
       newState.markers.coordinates = responseJson;
       this.setState(newState);
       //Alert.alert(responseJson+ " ")
      //Alert.alert('https://isg.info.tr/query_maps.php' + '?latitude=' + this.state.latitude + '&longitude=' + this.state.longitude);
       //this.markers = responseJson;
    console.log(responseJson);
     })
     .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
     });
     //Alert.alert(responseJson);
   };
   render() {
      return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView
      style={styles.map}
      region={{
        latitude: this.state.latitude,
        longitude: this.state.longitude,
        latitudeDelta: 0.015,
        longitudeDelta: 0.015,
      }}
      onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange.bind(this)}
      >
      {this.state.markers.map((marker, index) => (
        <MapView.Marker key={index} coordinate={marker.coordinates} title={marker.title} />
      ))}
    </MapView>
      </View>
      );
   }
}
```

Json file from the query on the main server

```
[{"latitude" : 40.3565,"longitude" : 27.9774},{"latitude" : 40.3471,"longitude" : 27.9598},{"latitude" : 40,"longitude" : 27.9708}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a copy of your state in `onRegionChange`. That includes `this.state.latitude` and `this.state.longitude` which do not update at all when you do `setState` after your `fetch` call. Because of this, once `setState` executes, the map will "snap back" to whatever was last saved in your `state`.

One way to fix this is to update your `region` controlled `state` values with what is passed to `onRegionChange` like this (using your coding style):

```
.then((responseJson) => {
  const newState = Object.assign({}, this.state);
  newState.markers.coordinates = responseJson;
  newState.latitude = region.latitude;
  newState.longitude = region.longitude;
  this.setState(newState);
  console.log(responseJson);
})
```

Alternatively, update that part of your `state` first in case you are relying on having up-to-date `region` information (`latitude`, `longitude`) elsewhere in your code. Then call the `fetch` in the `setState` callback:

```
onRegionChange (region) {
  this.setState({
    latitude: region.latitude,
    longitude: region.longitude,
  }, () => {
    fetch('https://isg.info.tr/query_maps.php' + '?latitude=' + 
    // ...the rest of your fetch call code here as is...
  });
};
```

If it we me though, I would simply not make a wholesale copy of your `state`. It's not a very normal practice in React and is inefficient when dealing with lots of data in `state`. So instead, I'd probably opt to only update the part of `state` that needs to be updated (`markers`):

```
.then((responseJson) => {
  let markers = [...this.state.markers];
  markers.coordinates = responseJson;
  this.setState({ markers });
  console.log(responseJson);
})
```

Note that I'm not updating your `latitude` and `longitude` values stored in `state` because the `MapView` should work fine if all you do is set `region` once and then never update the values used by it. However, if that is your use case and you do not intend on ever controlling your `region`, I suggest using the `initialRegion` prop instead. It will lead to fewer errors like this in the future.

Comment: Hello, I edited the file as you informed me and make a small change in the Json file that is returned by the server. Then updated the question with changes. The markers on location change doesn't show up at the moment

Comment: @EnginY. I have work today so I can't take a look. However, [you shouldn't be editing questions with new issues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106250/282178) as it makes it more broad and less useful to others with similar questions. Especially since you've changed more than one thing (e.g., the JSON returned from the server) and it's now deviated greatly from the original issue. You should post the new issue as a new question instead and revert the edits you made to this question.

Comment: thanks @michael_cheng turned back to initial revision. Then I asked on this address https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49831855/react-native-dynamically-pop-and-show-map-markers-from-server

Answer (score 0):

Try this, put your marker in center of map, when user move the map, get the last location with onRegionChangeComplete. You can read the concept from this link

https://alizahid.dev/blog/keep-marker-in-center-and-move-map-around-it